# How do I get the index of a character as it occurs in a regular expression?

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-5

In Ruby (using RoR 5.0.1), I want to get the index of the number "2" in the text block

```
"\n2 hel2 lo"
```

However I only want the index of the two if it is preceded by white space or the start of the line and is followed by white space.  So I whipped up this little regex

```
2.4.0 :007 > regex = /([[:space:]]|^)2([[:space:]]|\.|\))/
 => /([[:space:]]|^)2([[:space:]]|\.|\))/
2.4.0 :008 > text_content = "\n2 hel2 lo"
 => "\n2 hel2 lo"
2.4.0 :009 > text_content.index(regex)
 => 0
```

but clearly this regex returns zero since that is where the regex first occurs.  I want an expression that will return back "1", since 1 is the index of where the "2" occurs in the regex.  How do I do this?

Comment: Well, try http://ideone.com/vwVGtA

Comment: `text_content.index(/(?<=[\n\s])\d\s/)` might be okay.

Comment: @sagarpandya82, what if I wanted to match the beginning of a line or a space prior to the number?  I tried /(?<=([[:space:]]|^))\d\s/ but got the error " invalid pattern in look-behind: /(?<=([[:space:]]|^))\d\s/"

Comment: @Wiktor, shoudl have tried your suggestion first -- /(?<![^[:space:]])2([[:space:].)])/ returns the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex matches correctly at the start of the string, but you only need to grab the position of the pattern starting at `2`, thus, I'd suggest turning the `([[:space:]]|^)` part into a `(?<![^[:space:]])` negative lookbehind:

```
regex = /(?<![^[:space:]])2([[:space:].)])/
text_content = "\n2 hel2 lo"
text_content.index(regex)  
# => 1
```

See the [Ruby demo](http://ideone.com/vwVGtA).

The `(?<![^[:space:]])` lookbehind (matching a location to the left of the current one that is not preceded with a non-whitespace) is a zero-width assertion and will only be checked for presence, and the text won't be part of the match, thus, you will get the correct location.

Comment: Why not `/(?<=\s|^)2\s/`?

Comment: @dawg: [`[:space:]` is Unicode aware](http://ideone.com/NxIhwe), and `\s` at the end does not match `.` and `)` (while OP pattern does).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/(?<=\s|^)2\s/`:

```
> "\n2 hel2 lo".index(/(?<=\s|^)2\s/)
=> 1
> "2 hel2 lo".index(/(?<=\s|^)2\s/)
=> 0
> "abc 2 hel2 lo".index(/(?<=\s|^)2\s/)
=> 4
> "abc  hel2 lo".index(/(?<=\s|^)2\s/)
=> nil
```

Note that it won't match at the end of the string:

```
> "abchel2 lo 2".index(/(?<=\s|^)2\s/)
=> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

```
r = /
    (?<!\S)  # do not match a non-whitespace character (negative lookbehind)
    2        # match 2
    (?=\s)   # match a whitespace character in a positive lookahead
    /x       # free-spacing regex definition mode

"\n2 hel2 lo" =~ r  #=> 1
"42 hel 2 lo" =~ r  #=> 7
"42 hel*2 lo" =~ r  #=> nil
```

If it is intended for the index `0` to be returned for the one-character string `"2"`, change the regex to

```
r = /(?<!\S)2(?!\S)/
"2" =~ r  #=> 0`
```

`(?!\S)` is a negative lookahead that stipulates that `"2"` must not be followed by a non-whitespace character.

If the string may contain more than one `"2"` that satisfies the conditions, and indices are needed for all matches, one can use [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-scan) with the same regex as just given (`r = /(?<!\S)2(?!\S)/`). (I've assumed that a `"2"` at the end of the string is a match if it is preceded by a whitespace character or is also at the beginning of the string.)

```
arr = []
"\n2 302 2 2".scan(r) { arr << Regexp.last_match.begin(0) }
arr
  # => [1, 7, 9]
```

See [String#=~](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-3D-7E), [Regexp::last_match](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Regexp.html#method-c-last_match)<sup>1</sup> and [MatchData#begin](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/MatchData.html#method-i-begin).

<sup>1 `Regexp.last_match` returns the value of the global variable `$~`.</sup>